# Sudden issue in Looker Studio: "Looker Studio has encountered a system error." broke charts

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dashboard, looker-studio

We use Looker Studio to make dashboards using BigQuery tables as the data source. Today morning, suddenly all/most of our charts are broken on some important dashboards (not all dashboards though)

The only error msg is:

```
Looker Studio has encountered a system error.
Sorry, we encountered an error and were unable to complete your request.
Error ID: 260f07b4
```

If we change filters, sometimes some charts show up:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v5YgA.png)

Is anyone else facing such issues?

I tried copying the charts and creating new charts and cards.

They show data for some time but after refreshing the dashboard, they go broken again.

Same for copying the dashboard - the copy also shows broken charts.

Comment: Thanks for the question. I was facing the same issue. If anyone finds some answers, please share them.

Comment: I experience the same thing. I found that changing an aggregation type from average to something else, it works. But it may break again on refresh. I suspected some new features / release to be the cause. A user on twitter found that a few new features arrived today: https://twitter.com/wissi_analytics/status/1735247219798745515 however it is not reflected in the official changelog (at this time of writing): https://support.google.com/looker-studio/answer/11521624?hl=en&ref_topic=6267740&sjid=1668758263024083029-EU

I also reported the error to google . Will follow post 

Answer (score 3):

Problem seems to be fixed. All tables are working again for us

Comment: The error is gone for me as well! That is some nice progress. 
However some of my time-graphs are still not rendering any data. Those timegraphs broke at the same time I got the other error. I hope google continues to investigate and fix.

Answer (score 0):

We have same problem with this,too.

When I tried to clone the metrics or create new dashboard, it worked until I click on refresh or reopen it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).